# Using Entity Framwork to add records vs using ado to call a stored procedure that adds records into a database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are using Entity Framework 4.0 and we had a situation where we were adding records to a database using code similar to below and it was timing out.  We swapped out the Entity Framework  call for an ADO.Net call to a stored procedure and it completed in 15 seconds.  Any ideas?

Any chance not having this code wrapped in a "using" could cause this issue?

```
ENTITY-TABLENAME d = new ENTITY-TABLENAME();

d.COLUMN1 = batchNo;
d.COLUMN2 = lineNo;
d.COLUMN3 = "N";
d.COLUMN4 = "N";
d.COLUMN5 = year;
d.COLUMN6 = month;
d.COLUMN7 = distributorPA;
d.COLUMN8 = dealerPA;
d.COLUMN9 = dealerPA;
d.COLUMN10 = fordPartNo;
d.COLUMN11 = quantity;
d.COLUMN12 = "0";
d.COLUMN13 = 0;
d.COLUMN14 = 0;
d.COLUMN15 = 0;
d.COLUMN16 = "";
d.COLUMN17 = User.Identity.Name;
d.COLUMN18 = DateTime.Now;
d.COLUMN19 = User.Identity.Name;
d.COLUMN20= DateTime.Now;

db.ENTITY-TABLENAME.Add(d);
```

Comment: Do other queries work using EF? If not, then I suspect that the configuration files needs to be checked out

Answer (score 1):

No suspect in this query. I cannot believe that a query using no relations, no references, including only one table could cause a time out. Are you sure there was no complex relations involved? No foreign keys? No referencing to other table entities?

I would also say that needing 15 seconds to execute is too slow, regardless if you use a stored procedure or entity framework! Perhaps something is wrong with your SQL Server, or the specific computer in general. You should check its resource availability using the [respective tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd450363.aspx) like [Monitor Resource Usage tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191246.aspx).

Anyway, no assumptions are safe regarding performance. I would use a profiler like the [SQL Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to see the actual SQL query on which the LINQ to Entities query is translated. I am sure that it could provide useful insights.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Glad to help. Since you found my answer helpful, please upvote it. It is crucial for users navigating to your question to be able to identify if an answer was helpful or not...